# Problem with NewtonJson deserialization json from stored procedure which return result for json

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.Id as [ProdList.ProdId],
    @Main1 as [ProdList.Main],
    a.Hit as [ProdList.Hit],
    a.New as [ProdList.New],
    a.Sale as [ProdList.Sale],
    a.Price as [ProdList.Price],
    a.Price_old as [ProdList.OldPrice],
    a.Sort as [ProdList.Sort],
    a.ShName as [ProdList.Name],
    c.Big as [ProdList.ImagePath],
    a.SaleSize  as [ProdList.SaleSize],
    '' as [ProdList.QueryString],
    0 as [ProdList.RANK],
    (SELECT 
         ('/products/product/'+cast(f.Id as nvarchar(255))) as [Link],
         g.Big as [Img]
     FROM
         Products f
     INNER JOIN
         GroupProducts d ON d.ProdId = f.Id
     INNER JOIN
         ProdImages g ON g.ProdId = f.Id
     WHERE  
         d.ParentId = a.Id AND g.Main = 1
     FOR JSON PATH) AS [GroupProduct]
FROM 
    Products a
INNER JOIN 
    ProdInCategory b ON a.Id = b.ProdId
INNER JOIN 
    ProdImages c ON a.Id = c.ProdId
INNER JOIN 
    GroupProducts e ON a.Id = e.ProdId
WHERE
    c.Main = 1 AND b.CatId = @CatId AND e.ParentId = 0

UNION

SELECT 
    a.Id as [ProdList.ProdId],
    @Main1 as [ProdList.Main],
    a.Hit as [ProdList.Hit],
    a.New as [ProdList.New],
    a.Sale as [ProdList.Sale],
    a.Price as [ProdList.Price],
    a.Price_old as [ProdList.OldPrice],
    a.Sort as [ProdList.Sort],
    a.ShName as [ProdList.Name],
    g.Big as [ProdList.ImagePath],
    a.SaleSize  as [ProdList.SaleSize],
    '' as [ProdList.QueryString],
    0 as [ProdList.RANK],
    null as [GroupProduct]
FROM
    Products a
INNER JOIN 
    ProdImages g ON g.ProdId = a.Id
INNER JOIN 
    ProdInCategory pc ON a.Id = pc.ProdId
WHERE
    a.Id NOT IN (SELECT ProdId FROM GroupProducts) 
    AND pc.CatId = @CatId
FOR JSON PAT
```

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application I run this stored procedure and deserialize result to object:

```
string query = String.Format("EXEC   [dbo].[GetListProdId3] @CatId={0}", incommingModel.id);
        var result = string.Concat(db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query));

        List<ProdList> tovarListJson1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProdList>>(result);
```

The first select to union takes all the row filled with GroupProduct. The second select after the union takes the rest of the products from the category that have no group (Not in GroupProduct). If Im comment out half of the selection before the union statement in SP,  then everything works(Independently before union select top or bottom). If Im try to run the whole select with the union statement, I get the error:

[image]

My class to deserialization :

```
public class ProdList
{
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    public bool Main { get; set; }
    public bool Hit { get; set; }
    public bool New { get; set; }
    public bool Sale { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Sort { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string SaleSize { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public string QueryString { get; set; }
    public List<NestedProdList> GroupProduct { get; set; }
}
```

My json from stored procedure(first element and last):

```
[{"ProdList":{"ProdId":225,"Main":true,"Hit":false,"New":false,"Sale":false,"Price":22.0000,"OldPrice":0.0000,"Sort":23.5200,"Name":"Ручка шариковая \"Tris Lx\", синяя","ImagePath":"\/images2\/44012\/ruchka-sharikovaya-tris-1.jpg","SaleSize":"0%        ","QueryString":"","RANK":0},"GroupProduct":"[{\"Link\":\"\\\/products\\\/product\\\/23091\",\"Img\":\"\\\/images2\\\/40554\\\/ruchka-sharikovaya-tris-1.jpg\"},{\"Link\":\"\\\/products\\\/product\\\/32836\",\"Img\":\"\\\/images2\\\/40555\\\/ruchka-sharikovaya-tris-1.jpg\"},{\"Link\":\"\\\/products\\\/product\\\/32918\",\"Img\":\"\\\/images2\\\/44010\\\/ruchka-sharikovaya-tris-1.jpg\"},{\"Link\":\"\\\/products\\\/product\\\/37093\",\"Img\":\"\\\/images2\\\/44011\\\/ruchka-sharikovaya-tris-1.jpg\"},{\"Link\":\"\\\/products\\\/product\\\/56573\",\"Img\":\"\\\/images2\\\/40553\\\/ruchka-sharikovaya-tris-1.jpg\"}]"},{"ProdList":{"ProdId":68812,"Main":true,"Hit":false,"New":false,"Sale":false,"Price":9.2000,"OldPrice":20.8900,"Sort":21.5600,"Name":"MIR FANTASY, ручка шариковая","ImagePath":"\/images2\/63849\/mir-fantasy-ruchka-1.jpg","SaleSize":"0%        ","QueryString":"","RANK":0},"GroupProduct":null},{"ProdList":{"ProdId":69329,"Main":true,"Hit":false,"New":false,"Sale":false,"Price":27.0000,"OldPrice":0.0000,"Sort":31.3600,"Name":"Ручка шариковая \"Twisty Safe Touch\", светло-голубая","ImagePath":"\/images2\/11763\/ruchka-sharikovaya-twisty-1.jpg","SaleSize":"0%        ","QueryString":"","RANK":0},"GroupProduct":null}]
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the ProdList class and the results get from ssms for your stored procedure

Comment: Thx you you have must field in your json result than in your class i didn’t say if it’s way but it’s can be a start point

Comment: Please edit your additional info directly into the question.